# How can I see all plugins published on the Aragon OSx protocol?

Tags: solidity, protocol, registries

I want to see all plugins available to me within the Aragon OSx protocol. What's the easiest way to see that?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to see them is to query the subgraph:

- Goerli: https://subgraph.satsuma-prod.com/aragon/osx-goerli/playground.
- Mainnet: https://subgraph.satsuma-prod.com/aragon/osx-mainnet/playground

Then, you want to pass in this query:

```
query GetPlugins {
  pluginRepos {
      subdomain
    }
}
```

Note that you don't need any additional headers or variables to make the query.
To find out all available information to query, you can head over to `pluginRepos` within the documentation. Attached a screenshot below as reference.

[image: Current docs]

Answer (score 1):

Adding to this, one common gotcha is when querying the subgraph, make sure the addresses are lowercase, otherwise the subgraph will return null.